# Is there a way to simplify the case logic for an enum in verilog?

Tags: class, verilog, traits, vivado

I'm looking to simplify an expression for decoding the opcode for a risc v microcontroller:

```
always @ * begin
    case (opcode)
        LOAD | LOAD_FP | MISC_MEM | OP_IMM  OP_IMM_32 : begin // I_TYPE
            imm[0] <= inst[20];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[24:21];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
        end
        STORE | STORE_FP | AMO : begin // S_TYPE
            imm[0] <= inst[7];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[11:8];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
        end
        BRANCH, JALR : begin // B_TYPE
            imm[0] <= 0;
            imm[4:1] <= inst[11:8];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[11] <= inst[7];
            imm[31:12] <= inst[31];
        end
        AUIPC, LUI, OP_32 : begin // U_TYPE
            imm[11:0] <= 0;
            imm[19:12] <= inst[19:12];
            imm[30:20] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31] <= inst[31];
        end
        JAL, SYSTEM : begin // J_TYPE
            imm[0] <= 0;
            imm[4:1] <= inst[24:21];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[11] <= inst[20];
            imm[19:12] <= inst[19:12];
            imm[31:20] <= inst[30];
        end
        default :
            imm <= 0;   
    endcase 
end
```

to somewthing like this:

```
always @ * begin
    case (opcode)
        I_TYPE : begin
            imm[0] <= inst[20];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[24:21];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
        end
        S_TYPE : begin
            imm[0] <= inst[7];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[11:8];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
       end
       // ...continued
       default :
            imm <= 0;   
    endcase 
end
```

Is this possible, can I add methods to an enum/class like in c++, is this worth doing, if so how?
this is my enum:

```
typedef enum logic [6:2] {
  LOAD   = 5'b00_000,  LOAD_FP  = 5'b00_001,  CUSTOM_0   = 5'b00_010,  MISC_MEM = 5'b00_011,  OP_IMM = 5'b00_100,  AUIPC      = 5'b00_101,  OP_IMM_32 = 5'b00_110,  OP_48_1 = 5'b00_111,
  STORE  = 5'b01_000,  STORE_FP = 5'b01_001,  CUSTOM_1   = 5'b01_010,  AMO      = 5'b01_011,  OP     = 5'b01_100,  LUI        = 5'b01_101,  OP_32     = 5'b01_110,  OP_64   = 5'b01_111,
  MADD   = 5'b10_000,  MSUB     = 5'b10_001,  NMSUB      = 5'b10_010,  NMADD    = 5'b10_011,  OP_FP  = 5'b10_100,  RESERVED_6 = 5'b10_101,  CUSTOM_2  = 5'b10_110,  OP_48_2 = 5'b10_111,
  BRANCH = 5'b11_000,  JALR     = 5'b11_001,  RESERVED_A = 5'b11_010,  JAL      = 5'b11_011,  SYSTEM = 5'b11_100,  RESERVED_D = 5'b11_101,  CUSTOM_3  = 5'b11_110,  OP_80   = 5'b11_111
} base_opcode_map;
```

If not can somebody tell me the kind of pattern I need to follow?

Comment: Can't you do `case (opcode & 5'b11_000)`? Then `I_TYPE` is `5'b00_000`, `S_TYPE` is `0b01_000`, and so on

Comment: My apologies, I don't quite understand, is there something I've missed about how the risc v operations are encoded, I should note I've asked a similar question to Reddit and came out with no answers so I'd be interested to hear anything you might think would be helpful?

Comment: it is not, I found it here, my mistake
https://insights.sigasi.com/tech/case-statements-vhdl-verilog/

Comment: You **cannot** add *methods* to enums neither in verilog nor in c++.  You can wrap it in a class but it will not be synthesizable in verilog. In my opinion, what you have is already simple enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few things you can do.  You can use a `let` construct

```
let I_TYPE = opcode inside {LOAD, LOAD_FP, MISC_MEM, OP_IMM, OP_IMM_32};
let S_TYPE = opcode inside {STORE, STORE_FP, AMO};
...
```

`let` is a shorthand for defining a simple function

```
function bit I_TYPE;
  return opcode inside {LOAD, LOAD_FP, MISC_MEM, OP_IMM, OP_IMM_32};
endfunction 
function bit S_TYPE;
  return opcode inside {STORE, STORE_FP, AMO};
endfunction
```

Then you can write a `case` statement

```
always @ * begin
    case (1'b1)
        I_TYPE : begin
            imm[0] <= inst[20];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[24:21];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
        end
        S_TYPE : begin
            imm[0] <= inst[7];
            imm[4:1] <= inst[11:8];
            imm[10:5] <= inst[30:25];
            imm[31:11] <= inst[31];
       end
       // ...continued
       default :
            imm <= 0;   
    endcase 
end
```

Comment: Thank you dave, I get a bit confused sometimes,  is this worth  doing  or does  it make it harder for vivado tho simplify the netlist

Comment: @LyndonAlcock, I don't think it makes any difference as long as Vivado supports it--it represents equivalent logic equations. It's only worth doing if there are more places you need `I_TYPE` without having to repeat the list.

Comment: thank you, well i figured ill need it when I'm decoding the instruction (obviously) as well as at the ALU to determine what the ALU needs to perform, however, i could be wrong, I'm very new to this business.